# Missing macOS Template in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have been looking around for hours and going back in circles.

I built an iOS app using Visual Studio (Xamarin.iOS) and as long as my Visual studio is connected to my Mac, I can build the solution and work on it. Same seems to be the case for watchOS and Apple tvOS as well but I am unable to find **macOS** app template in Visual Studio (Windows) - As shown in the following screenshot

[image: Screenshot 1]

> Where I have installed **Xamarin.Mac SDK** as shown in the following
>   screenshot

[image: Screenshot 2]

Is it just not possible or am I having a bad day? If I can recall my previous installation of Visual Studio did have **macOS** (Or I might just be losing my mind). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can always just create it via VS4M and copy it over (or `git` it, etc...) Remember though, while you can "compile" a non-functional assembly for Xamarin.Mac to check for compiler/code errors, you can not run it from VS4W, you will need access to your mac (physically or via screen sharing)

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for your reply - Well said about the limitations, I was just wondering if it is possible to have VS template installed for macOS instead of copy/pasting solution from my Mac

Comment: I just checked my VSFW 2019 install, it does not have a macOS template either. I personally have never tried it before as I just use VS4M to create them as they are non-debuggable from Windows anyway (you have to have VS4M installed), same goes the other way for UWP projects, have to have VS4W as VS4M does not have UWP templates available....

Comment: Thanks, @SushiHangover - I guess I don't have any option now, The main reason I wanted to use VS4W was the ability to edit Storyboards without getting them opened in XCode, It seems like VS4M opens an instance of XCode when I edit my Storeboard where that is not the case when editing Scoreboards for Xamarin.iOS in VS4W, The other reason was the comfort of working on Windows as VS4M feels diffrrent than VS4W - But I guess I will have to give it a try and get used to it. However, I wonder if MS has any plans to provide template directly in VS4W as everything else is provided (tvOS, watchOS etc)

Comment: Yeah, xamarin does not have a custom designer for Mac storyboards, you have to use xcode. Mac/Cocoa development has always had a very low usage within the xamarin user base

Comment: Thanks for your help :) Yeah it makes sense now. I moved the project on Windows, I can open it and Build it ok Although the Storyboard displays the message 'the file target macOS, the designer supports watchOS, iOS and tvOS only' :) I am surprised the VS4W designer doesn't support macOS while supporting all others

Comment: Cocoa has totally different UI controls

Comment: Oh wow... Ok cheers